# How to open installed app with url_launcher else open in browser?

Tags: flutter, dart

like the title suggests, I use url_launcher to open some websites when the user taps a selected icon. The issue is that it opens the browser website if the associated app is not installed on the device otherwise nothing happens if said app is installed. The app just doesn't respond. From what I've read, its supposed to open the associated app anyway? Or am I mistaken?

Here's the onTap:

```
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _launchTwitchURL,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/icon_twitch.png', // On click should redirect to an URL
                      width: 40.0,
                      height: 40.0,
                    ),
                  ),
```

And here's the call:

```
  Future<void> _launchTwitchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/example';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: To open the app, you need to use android-intent. Url launcher can only launches your url.

Comment: Like the same way you would use android-intent in the manifest for an Android app in Java/Kotlin?

Comment: No, I meant you should use [`android-intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) package for opening the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [android-intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) package like @iDecode suggested to get it to work. [appavailability](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability) might be a better suited/cleaner package depending on your needs.

```
  Future<void> _launchTwitchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/example';
    
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
        action: 'action_view',
        data: 'https://www.twitch.tv/example', // replace com.example.app with your applicationId
      );
      await intent.launch();
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Thanks @iDecode